# How to only allow a certain component parameter type for React High Order Components in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I started learning React yesterday and came across the concept of Higher-Order Components. I'm trying to create a function that takes an existing `Button` (from the MUI components library) as a parameter and returns a stylized version of that button with the base styles I provide.

The code for the HOC:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

import { Colors } from "@/constants";

const withBaseStyles = <T extends typeof Button>(
  WrappedButton: React.ComponentType<T>
) => {
  // At this point, the props being passed in are the original props the component expects.
  const StyledButton = (props: T) => (
    <WrappedButton
      variant="outlined"
      size="large"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeCompliment,
        color: Colors.primary,
        borderColor: Colors.primary,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
  return StyledButton;
};

export { withBaseStyles };
```

The code where I'm trying to use the HOC:

```
import React from "react";
import { Box, Grid, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { withBaseStyles } from "../OnboardingBaseButton/OnboardingBaseButton";

const OriginalButton = () => <Button>Hello</Button>;
const StyledButton = withBaseStyles(OriginalButton);

const Welcome = () => {
  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      sx={{ height: "100%" }}
    >
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h6" align="center" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
          Welcome PERSON
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" align="center" sx={{ p: 2 }}>
          We’re thrilled to have you part of our team as we work together to
          change the way small businesses communicate with their customers
        </Typography>
        <Box sx={{ mt: 8, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {/* <OnboardingMainButton variant="onboarding" /> */}
          <StyledButton />
        </Box>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR in src/views/Onboarding/OnboardingSteps/Welcome.tsx:28:12
TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>) => Element'.
  Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(props: { href: string; } & { children?: ReactNode; classes?: Partial<ButtonClasses> | undefined; color?: "inherit" | "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "error" | "info" | "warning" | undefined; ... 9 more ...; variant?: "text" | ... 2 more ... | undefined; } & Omit<...> & CommonProps & Omit<...>): Element'.
    26 |         <Box sx={{ mt: 8, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
    27 |           {/* <OnboardingMainButton variant="onboarding" /> */}
  > 28 |           <StyledButton />
       |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    29 |         </Box>
    30 |       </div>
    31 |     </Grid>
```

I may be using the wrong concept to solve my problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this might be out of the realm of what you were asking specifically, but are Material UI's provided ways to modify components not sufficient for you? I believe you can compose custom base style components by following the documentation here https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

I checked that out yesterday and I didn't do that because I didn't want to change the global button styles, I just want to do this for a few of the buttons.